# Авторизация в Firebasе

Tags: android, android-sdk, firebase

Начал работу с Firebase. Регистрацию написал, все работает. Пишу авторизацию, код вроде правильный, но при нажатии авторизоваться, ничего не происходит. В чем может быть проблема ?

```
public void signin(String email, String password){
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if(auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
    //Уже подписан, ничего не делать
    }
    else {
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    //Пользователь успешно подписан
                    Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this,"Welcome!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**Gradle:**

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
```

Comment: Вероятно у вас какая-то ошибка при авторизации. А т.к. нет `else` к `if(task.isSuccessful())` то ничего и не происходит при этой ошибке. Добавьте  `else` и выведите в логи всё что есть внутри `Task<AuthResult> task` - там будет объяснение что за ошибка у вас произошла.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб  можете подсказать,что я должен прописать в else?

Comment: Ну, например `task.getException().printStacktrace()`